# fading out the background color with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, animation

I got the AJAX post to get the latest comment like below:

```
function add_the_answer_to_the_list(dataString)
{
  // append this damn comment to the list
  $.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "home/get_answer/",
    data : dataString,
    success: function(data)
    {
      var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

      //append the comment
      $(
        '<li><article>'+data+ '</article></li>'
      ).hide().prependTo("#answer_list ul").fadeIn();

    }
  });
```

now, when the comment fading in what should i do to highlight the comment with red color then slowly fade the background color back to the original color? is there any way to do this kinda thing without plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I use JqueryUI core effect:

```
$(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CSS3 Transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) effect to do it.

**Example**

The CSS3 class to use - this will allow transitions for both opacity and background so it can 'fade in' and change color at the same time:

```
.comment {
opacity: 0;
background: #ff0000;
transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.comment-fade-in {
 background: #00ff00 /* make this your 'original color' */
 opacity: 1.0;
}
```

And now the javascript code:

```
function add_the_answer_to_the_list(dataString)
{
// append this damn comment to the list
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "home/get_answer/",
data : dataString,
success: function(data)
{
  var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

  //append the comment
  var comment = $('<li><article>'+data+ '</article></li>');
  comment.addClass('comment');
  comment.prependTo("#answer_list ul");
  comment.addClass('comment-fade-in');
}
```

});

Try that

Comment: good idea, would you give me an example how to implement that technique on the code?

Comment: For an example, loot at http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1

Comment: the example shows how to trigger the effect on hover event. but in my code i want the effect occurs when the ajax post is done. In other words, how to tell the css that the animation should start when the ajax is completed?

Comment: i don't know what really happened. when i test your code with hover, it runs smoothly. but when i tried to add the class with jquery, it doesn't work. it neither shows the fade in animation nor the background color. whats goin on here?

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
*
{   -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color .25s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color .25s ease-out;
    transition: background-color .25s ease-out; }

.highlight
{   background: red; }
```

JQuery for your ajax callback function:

```
$('<li><article>'+data+ '</article></li>')
.hide()
.prependTo("#answer_list ul")
.fadeIn(500, function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight')
    .delay(500)
    .removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That needs a plugin if you don't want to use CSS3 transitions or animations. By using the [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) plugin, you can animate the background color using jQuery's `.animate()` method.

```
$(ele).animate({backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0)'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UIs `switchClass`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DH8jK/1/

In your example:

```
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "home/get_answer/",
data : dataString,
success: function(data)
{
  var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

  //append the comment
  $(
    '<li><article>'+data+ '</article></li>'
  ).hide().prependTo("#answer_list ul").fadeIn().switchClass('class-with-background', 'class-without-background', 2000);

}
```

See http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/ for more informations.

**EDIT**

It is even easier with `removeClass` (http://jqueryui.com/removeClass/)

```
$(
    '<li class="class-with-background"><article>'+data+ '</article></li>'
  ).hide().prependTo("#answer_list ul").fadeIn().removeClass('class-without-background', 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery color plugin which is merely `1.7 KB` when minified

I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vKaYJ/

Comment: please read my question carefully dude. I need to do it without plugin. thanks